# Use Ajax variables in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been working on a site built by someone else, and every time there is an Ajax call in the site there's a div showing a progress bar.  In once instance though I would like to hide this bar (or better: not show it), but I don't know how to get my Ajax variables in this function.

The Ajax call is a very simple:

```
$.ajax({url: url, ...
```

and somwhere else in the code the function is added:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#progressbar').modal('show');
    });
```

I would love to add something to the ajax call like

```
$.ajax({url: url, hideProgressBar: true, ...
```

and then use the false to stop the progressbar from showing.  Anyone?

Comment: you don't have access to the ajax options within ajaxStart.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `global` option to false in your AJAX properties for that call:

```
global: false,
```

Comment: @MichaelNieuwenhuizen `ajaxStart` is a global handler, which you can turn off by setting the property `gloabl: false`.  None of the global handlers will run when you do that, hence your code to show the progress bar is never run :)

Comment: Thanks!  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ajaxSend` instead of `ajaxStart`...

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, jqXHR, options) {
    if (options.showProgressBar) {
        $('#progressbar').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Then make your ajax calls like this...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://etc..",
    showProgressBar: false
});
```

You can put any options you like in the ajax call and they'll be accessible in the send event handler, in the options object.

**Note:** I know I've used `showProgressBar` and you were talking about hiding it, but that's just me.  Change that, if needed, to suit :)

Comment: I understand showProgressBar makes more sense, but it's a big site and I would have to add `showProgressBar: true` to all the ajax calls in the site.  Since it's a big site and I didn't wanna mess things up it's easier and safer fore more to add a hideProgressBar in my code.

Comment: @MichaelNieuwenhuizen Yep, I understand.  tymeJV's answer above is definitely more suited to your needs then.